# Tips for debugging NFS mounts in systemd

Tags: nfs, systemd, coreos

I'm running CoreOS, which uses systemd. I have several NFS mounts which work fine on my Ubuntu 14 system, but are not reliably connected at startup under systemd. I've defined them like this (where `remote` is my NAS):

```
- name: mnt-documents.mount
  contents: |
    [Unit]
    After=nfs-client.target
    Requires=nfs-client.target
    [Mount]
    What=remote:/volume1/Documents
    Where=/mnt/documents
    Type=nfs
    Options=rw,vers=3
- name: mnt-documents.automount
  contents: |
    [Automount]
    Where=/mnt/documents
```

I have 4 of these, all mounting different directories from the same NFS server. Sometimes 1 fails, sometimes 2, sometimes they all work.  If I try `systemctl status mnt-documents.mount` I get

```
● mnt-documents.mount - /mnt/documents
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mnt-documents.mount; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-02-26 09:55:24 UTC; 5h 10min ago
    Where: /mnt/documents
     What: remote:/volume1/Documents
  Process: 983 ExecMount=/bin/mount remote:/volume1/Documents /mnt/documents -t nfs -o rw,vers=3 (code=exited, status=32)

Feb 26 09:55:23 tularemia systemd[1]: Mounting /mnt/documents...
Feb 26 09:55:24 tularemia systemd[1]: mnt-documents.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Feb 26 09:55:24 tularemia systemd[1]: mnt-documents.mount: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 26 09:55:24 tularemia systemd[1]: Failed to mount /mnt/documents.
```

If I try to run the `mount` command myself, it always succeeds.

I'm suspicious that the problem is that the mount is happening (sometimes) before DNS is active. But my question here is how to understand the failure better? I'm not sure what `status=32` is, and I'm not sure how to ask the mount-unit to pass the `-v` flag to `mount`.